# Error on calling power shell script from vbs passing arguments

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a very simple VBScript that executes a PowerShell script and am trying to pass several parameters.

No matter what I've tried, it is failing and not accepting arguments:

```vb
Dim WshShell
Dim cmdStr
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2 ,ForAppending = 8
curYear = Year(Date)
curMon  = Month(Date)
curDay  = Day(Date)
curHr   = Hour(Time)
curMin  = Minute(Time)
curSec  = Second(Time)

datestg = curYear & curMon & curDay & curHr & curMin & curSec

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim inputDir
inputDir = InputBox("Input Directory ( can be full file path ) : ", "Message Box")

inputDirLen = Len(inputDir)

If inputDirLen > 0 Then
    lastchar = Mid(inputDir, inputDirLen-1, 1)
    If lastchar <> "\" Then
        inputDir = inputDir & "\"
    End If
End If

outFileMask = InputBox("Output file name mask ( files will be created in previously entered directory ) : ", "Message Box")
newDate = InputBox("Desired Date ( format of the date should be yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss ) : ", "Message Box")

cmdStr = "%comspec% /c dir " & inputDir & "*.xml > dir.lst"
cmdrc = wshShell.Run(cmdStr, , True)

'create file system object
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dirFileName = "dir.lst"

outFileName  = inputDir & outFileMask & "_" & datestg &".xml"
Set infile   = fs.OpenTextFile(dirFileName, ForReading)
Set fileOut  = fso.CreateTextFile(outFileName, True)
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run("powershell -NoExit -File  .\psscript.ps1 " & infile)

infile.Close
fileOut.Close
WScript.Quit
```

This even fails on `objshell.Run`. If I take away any arg then it will run, but will fail in the PowerShell script due to the null values in argument.

Here is the full PowerShell script:

```bsh
$inputPath  = $args[0]
$newDate    = $args[1]
$outputPath = $args[2]

[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $inputPath

foreach ($element in $xmlDoc.element1) {
    $element.DateTime = $newDate
}

$xmlDoc.Save($outputPath)
```

Comment: have you tried echoing the `$inputPath` variable or using named arguments, yet?

Comment: BTW, don't create multiple instances of `WScript.Shell` and `Scripting.FileSystemObject` in your scripts. If you need one of these objects: create one instance at the beginning of your script (in a global variable) and use that instance throughout the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VBScript is opening the file with the XML file listing and then trying to pass that handle to the PowerShell script. That doesn't work.

There are several things you could do here:

- Read the XML file listing in the VBScript and invoke the PowerShell script in a loop:

  ```vb
  Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  outFileName = inputDir & outFileMask & "_" & datestg &".xml"

  Set infile = fs.OpenTextFile(dirFileName, ForReading)
  Do Until infile.AtEndOfStream
      line = infile.ReadLine
      sh.Run "powershell -File .\your.ps1 " & line & " " & newDate & " " & outFileName
  Loop
  infile.Close
  ```

  However, this means you're spawning a new process for each iteration, which is bad performance-wise.
- Pass the file with the XML file listing to the PowerShell script:

  ```vb
  Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  outFileName = inputDir & outFileMask & "_" & newDate &".xml"
  dirFileName = sh.CurrentDirectory & "\" & dirFileName

  sh.Run "powershell -File .\your.ps1 " & dirFileName & " " & newDate & " " & outFileName
  ```

  You want to pass `dirFileName` with the full path to the file because it's not guaranteed that VBScript and PowerShell code will have the same working directory. Passing the listing instead of individual files would also require changes to your PowerShell code:

  ```bsh
  $inputPath  = $args[0]
  $newDate    = $args[1]
  $outputPath = $args[2]

  Get-Content $inputPath | ForEach-Object {
      [xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $_.FullName

      foreach ($element in $xmlDoc.element1) {
          $element.DateTime = $newDate
      }

      $xmlDoc.Save($outputPath)
  }
  ```
- Pass the input directory and let PowerShell do the listing:

  ```vb
  Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  outFileName = inputDir & outFileMask & "_" & newDate &".xml"

  sh.Run "powershell -File .\your.ps1 " & inputDir & " " & newDate & " " & outFileName
  ```

  Again, this would also require changes to your PowerShell code:

  ```bsh
  $inputPath  = $args[0]
  $newDate    = $args[1]
  $outputPath = $args[2]

  Get-ChildItem $inputPath -Filter '*.xml' | ForEach-Object {
      [xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $_.FullName

      foreach ($element in $xmlDoc.element1) {
          $element.DateTime = $newDate
      }

      $xmlDoc.Save($outputPath)
  }
  ```
- You could also do everything in PowerShell and drop VBScript entirely (which is arguably the cleanest approach):

  ```bsh
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [ValidateScript(Test-Path -LiteralPath $_)]
      [String]$inputPath,

      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [ValidatePattern('^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$')]
      [String]$newDate,

      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [String]$outFileMask
  )

  $datestg     = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
  $outFileName = Join-Path $inputPath, "${outFileMask}_${datestg}.xml"

  Get-ChildItem $inputPath -Filter '*.xml' | ForEach-Object {
      [xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $_.FullName

      foreach ($element in $xmlDoc.element1) {
          $element.DateTime = $newDate
      }

      $xmlDoc.Save($outFileName)
  }
  ```

Note, however, that with *all* of these approaches the PowerShell will overwrite the output file with each iteration. If you have more than one XML file to process and want them written to different output files you need to create individual output file names within the loop.

Comment: Great explanation.